# Как обозначить дефолтный title, если не смог получить title через file_get_contents?

Tags: php

С помощью file_get_contents получаю заголовки с сайтов

```
function page_title($url) {
    $fp = file_get_contents($url);
    if (!$fp) 
        return null;

    $res = preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $fp, $title_matches);
    if (!$res) 
        return null; 

    // Clean up title: remove EOL and excessive whitespace.
    $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title_matches[1]);
    $title = trim($title);

    return $title;
}
```

Нередко попадаются сайты без заголовков, у меня имеются дефолтные заголовки которые я могу сохранить в базу так `'my_title' => $item->my_title,`

```
        $db->add(array_merge($item->only(['title', 'wareUrl', 'description', 'user', 'user_id', 'youtube', 'activatedate']), [
            'id' => (4 * 10000000) + $item->id,
            'item_id' => $item->id,
            'type' => 4,
            'user_id' => $item->user['id'],
            'youtube' => video_youtube(''.$item->wareUrl.''),
            'title' => page_title(''.$item->wareUrl.''),
          //  'my_title' => $item->my_title,
            'activatedate' => $item->activatedate,
            'time' => microtime(true)
        ]));
```

Помогите создать конструкцию `} else {`, чтобы в случае отсутствия заголовка получаемого через file_get_contents, в базу заносился дефолтный заголовок `'my_title' => $item->my_title,`

Пробовал прописать `if` внутри `$db->add(array_merge($item->only(['title', 'wareUrl', 'description', 'user', 'user_id', 'youtube', 'activatedate']), [` получаю ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'title' => page_title(''.$item->wareUrl.'') ? : $item->my_title, // $item->my_title дефолтный тайтл
```

только в page_title() бы делать return false; вместо return null; и в конце этой функции сделать проверку на strlen например:

```
return strlen($title)>0 ? $title : false;
```

Ну или можно только в функции page_title(); заменить все return null; на return $item->my_title и в конце проверка return strlen($title)>0 ? $title : $item->my_title; только посмотри на область видимости $item, возможно надо добавить внутри функции global $item;

Comment: Nsk, спасибо, работает! В `page_title();` сделал так    `return $title;
        return strlen($title)>0 ? $title : false;`, верно?

Comment: @MicroRu только return strlen($title)>0 ? $title : false; перед ним  return $title; не нужен, он отработает вперед и до проверки дело не дойдет

Comment: Спасибо, работает как часы.

Answer (score 1):

```
$title = 'defaultTitle';
if (preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $fp, $title_matches)) {
    $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title_matches[1]);
    $title = trim($title);
}
return $title;
```